# Java 6: Unsupported @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") warning

Tags: java, compiler-construction, warnings, suppress-warnings, raw-types

I moved to a new machine which has the latest Sun's Java compiler and noticed some warnings in the existing Java 6 code. The Eclipse IDE, suggested that I annotate the assignment with:

```
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
```

For example:

```
class Foo<T> {
...
}
...
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
Foo foo = new Foo();
```

When I moved back to the machine with the older compiler (JDK 1.6.0_20), I have noticed that this older compiler now warns about the suppression of "rawtypes" warnings, claiming that this suppression is unsupported and proposing to replace it with @SuppressWarnings("unchecked"). Also, there were some places which the newest compiler, by default, made me to put both "unchecked" and "rawtypes" - compiling that code with the older compiler reproduces the same warning.

How can I enforce backward/forward compatibility between the two, so that neither compiler produces warnings?

Comment: Which version of Eclipse suggests `rawtypes`? I've never seen that. As far as I remember Eclipse always suggested `unchecked` when I encountered this case.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can use the `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` which is supported by both the eclipse compiler and javac.

But remember the `@SuppressWarnings` annotation is used by your compiler which can have its own values. The JLS only forces the compiler to understand the values "unchecked" and "deprecated" (for now).

> Compiler vendors should document the warning names they support in conjunction with this annotation type. *They are encouraged to cooperate to ensure that the same names work across multiple compilers*.

If you use Helios, you will need to set a specific option to allow `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` instead of `@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")`,

> In case it is not possible to update the code with the new token, the `suppressRawWhenUnchecked=true` system property can be set when starting Eclipse.

---

**Resources :**

- [JLS - @SuppressWarnings()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.6.3.5)
- [Eclipse JDT](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/whatsNew/jdt_whatsnew.html) (*Java Compiler*, *New "rawtypes" token for @SuppressWarnings annotation*)

---

EDIT: Here is the now unavailable knol article that was used as a reference, originally written by [Alex Miller](http://tech.puredanger.com/).

> ## @SuppressWarnings Annotation in Java
>
> Standard annotation for suppressing various warnings
>
> The SuppressWarnings annotation was added as a standard annotation in Java SE 5.
>
> ### Definition
>
> The [@SuppressWarnings](http://web.archive.org/web/20120416030053/http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/SuppressWarnings.html) annotation is defined in the Java Language Specification [section 9.6.1.5](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/interfaces.html#9.6.1.5).  This section states:
>
> > The annotation type `SuppressWarnings` supports programmer control over warnings otherwise issued by the Java compiler. It contains a single element that is an array of `String`. If a program declaration is annotated with the annotation `@SuppressWarnings(value = {S1, ... , Sk})`, then a Java compiler must not report any warning identified by one of S1, ... , Sk if that warning would have been generated as a result of the annotated declaration or any of its parts.
> >
> > Unchecked warnings are identified by the string "`unchecked`".
>
> The subsequent [section](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/interfaces.html#9.6.1.6) on `@Deprecation` also mentions that these warnings can be suppressed with `@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")`.
>
> ### Valid Warning Types
>
> The only two warning strings that are mentioned in the specification itself are "unchecked" and "deprecation".  However, the Sun JDK uses a larger set of strings in the compiler.  You can determine the current set by executing:
>
> ```
> javac -X
> ```
>
> which will show you (among other things) the valid settings for -Xlint.
>
> For example, Sun JDK 1.5 shows:
>
> - all  - suppress all warnings from this code
> - deprecation  - suppress warnings from using deprecated code
> - unchecked - suppress warnings from an unchecked call or an unchecked cast
> - fallthrough - suppress warnings if a switch falls through without finding a valid case (and no default)
> - path -
> - serial - suppress warnings if a Serializable class does not define a serialVersionUID
> - finally - suppress warnings from return within a finally (which will ignore return with the try)
>
> And Sun JDK 1.6 adds:
>
> - cast
> - divzero - suppress warnings if integer divide by zero is detected
> - empty
> - overrides
> - none
>
> IDEs and static analysis tools typically support a large number of other possible values for @SuppressWarnings.  These values correspond to specific static analysis checks performed by the IDE.
>
> ### Eclipse
>
> The Eclipse warning values for Eclipse 3.3 are [documented in the JDT docs](http://help.eclipse.org/help33/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/guide/jdt_api_compile.htm).
>
> - all - suppress all warnings
> - boxing - suppress warnings relative to boxing/unboxing operations
> - cast - suppress warnings relative to cast operations
> - dep-ann - suppress warnings relative to deprecated annotation
> - deprecation - suppress warnings relative to deprecation
> - fallthrough - suppress warnings relative to missing breaks in switch statements
> - finally - suppress warnings relative to finally block that don't return
> - hiding - suppress warnings relative to locals that hide variable
> - incomplete-switch - suppress warnings relative to missing entries in a switch statement (enum case)
> - nls - suppress warnings relative to non-nls string literals
> - null - suppress warnings relative to null analysis
> - restriction - suppress warnings relative to usage of discouraged or forbidden references
> - serial - suppress warnings relative to missing serialVersionUID field for a serializable class
> - static-access - suppress warnings relative to incorrect static access
> - synthetic-access - suppress warnings relative to unoptimized access from inner classes
> - unchecked - suppress warnings relative to unchecked operations
> - unqualified-field-access - suppress warnings relative to field access unqualified
> - unused - suppress warnings relative to unused code
>
> ### IntelliJ
>
> ### NetBeans
>
> ### Examples
>
> An example of specifying a single warning:
>
> ```
> @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
> public void methodWithScaryWarnings() {
>     List rawList = new ArrayList();
>     List<String> stringList = (List<String>)rawList;
> }
> ```
>
> An example of using two warnings:
>
> ```
> @SuppressWarnings({"unchecked","deprecation"})
> public void methodWithScaryWarnings() {
>     callDeprecatedMethod();
> }
> ```

Comment: The eclipse compiler in helios rejects `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` and suggests what leden said.

Comment: @Willi, You're right, I updated my post with more informations for helios.

Answer (score 4):

Note that Eclipse 3.5 doesnt understand rawtypes and flags a warning to switch to unchecked. It is frustrating that Eclipse came up with rawtypes annotation which causes more problems than solving. They should have just stuck with the standard one.