# Replacement for obsolete Hashtable class in Java

Tags: java

When I tried to use the hashtable class, Netbeans gave me an error saying:

> While still supported, these classes were made obsolete by the JDK1.2 collection classes, and should probably not be used in new development.

However, I can't seem to find an example online on a better replacement for `Hashtable`. Any suggestions?

Comment: In general, you should use a HashMap.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The most direct replacement of a [`Hashtable`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html) is a [`HashMap`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html).

One difference that *could* be important is that all relevant methods of `Hashtable` are synchronized while they are *not* synchronized on `HashMap`.

Comment: If you need the synchronization (provided by Hashtable), you can use [`Collections.synchronizedMap()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedMap(java.util.Map)) to decorate a normal `HashMap` or use [`ConcurrentHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) which allows concurrent reading and modifying without requiring locking.

Comment: But you'll be not be able to replace a Hashtable by a HashMap if you have a third tier library needing a HashMap or a Dictionary (super type of the HashMap) like the one in org.osgi.framework.BundleContext.registerService(String string, Object o, Dictionary<String, ?> dctnr) one.

Answer (score 7):

A better replacement for [`Hashtable`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html) is [`HashMap`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html).

As for being obsolete, I have no reference to it, but the Javadoc states:

> As of the Java 2 platform v1.2, this class was retrofitted to
>   implement the [`Map`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) interface, making it a member of the 
>   [Java Collections Framework](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/collections/index.html).

[`Hashtable`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html) is synchronized unlike [`HashMap`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html).

Answer (score 4):

You could probably use Hashmap:

```
Map<String, Integer> mymap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

Answer (score 4):

You should use HashMap, but it is not designed for concurrent environments, where you may use [`ConcurrentHashMap`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html).

OR

```
Map<K,V> myMap = Collections.synchronizedMap(/*any map instance*/);
```

Answer (score 3):

There are cases when a method outside your control requires an [`Hashtable`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html).
Java's own [`javax.management.ObjectName`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/management/ObjectName.html) is
such an example<sup>[1]</sup>.

When the external interface requires it you have to use `Hashtable`.
In netbeans, you can use:

```
@SupresssWarnings("UseOfObsoleteCollectionType")
```

to suppress the warning locally.

See

- [Java: complete list of @SuppressWarnings(...) parameters (in Netbeans)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4419252/java-complete-list-of-suppresswarnings-parameters-in-netbeans)
- [Suppress deprecated import warning in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1858021/suppress-deprecated-import-warning-in-java/20909204#20909204)

  ---

1: I wonder why they used `Hashtable` and not `HashMap`, since `ObjectName` is
available since 1.5 and `Hashtable` is obsolete since 1.2

Answer (score 2):

**Summary**

The closest replacement is HashMap (usually via the Map interface).

---

But note that Hashtable is thread-safe while HashMap is not. **This is not a problem in most cases** and it was intentional to make most Java collections non-thread-safe to avoid performance penalty for most common scenarios. But if you relied on Hashtable thread-safety and now need a replacement that would also be thread-safe then you have two options:

- If you need a simple synchronization wrapper for an existing Map - use Collections.synchronizedMap(...)
- If you need a class carefully and optimally designed for concurrent access - use ConcurrentHashMap (usually via the ConcurrentMap interface that extends the Map interface with additional concurrency features).