# Java JSlider: Dictionary is deprecated for method setLabelTable, what else should I use?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jslider

I am currently trying to setup a custom label for a JSlider in Java.

I looked up into the Java API and found this method: `public void setLabelTable(Dictionary labels)`

Unfortunately it turns out the `Dictionary` class and it's subclass `Hashtable` is obsolete.

According to the answer of this question: [Using Java Dictionary...use a Hashtable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11530661/using-java-dictionary-use-a-hashtable)

The `Hashtable` class has been 'replaced' with `HashMap`.

So I tried to send a `HashMap` instead of a `Hashtable`, which I highly doubted it would work.

As expected, the compiler gave me this error:

`incompatible types: HashMap<Integer, JLabel> cannot be converted to Dictionary`

I can choose to use the `Dictionary` and the `Hashtable` class and compile with `Xlint:Deprecated` and it will give me the result that I want.

But I don't want to use something that's been obsolete for a while.

What should I use instead of `setLabelTable(Dictionary labels)`?

Or is there no other way than using `setLabelTable(Dictionary labels)`?

[image: Desired Result]

I want to produce this GUI without using a deprecated or obsolete API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Dictionary` and `Hashtable` classes are deprecated for future use, and shouldn't be used for applications that just need to store key-value pairs.  (As you saw, new applications should use the Collections class `HashMap`.)

However, it is still perfectly fine to use the older classes for applications like yours where you are calling another function that needs a `Dictionary` or `Hashtable` as an argument.  You really don't have any choice.

If you wanted to minimize the amount of code in your project that used the older classes, you could use a `HashMap` to store your labels, and then use `setLabelTable` along with the `Hashtable` constructor that builds a `Hashtable` from a `HashMap` like this:

```
 mySlider.setLabelTable(new Hashtable(myLabelHashMap))
```