# Eclipse Helios - @SuppressWarnings "rawtypes" doesn't work while "unchecked" does

Tags: eclipse, ide, suppress-warnings, unchecked, raw-types

I have a problem with the `@SuppressWarnings` annotation when handling raw-types warnings in Eclipse Helios.

According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646770/java-6-unsupported-suppresswarningsrawtypes-warning) and the [docs](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/porting/3.6/incompatibilities.html), the annotation parameter `rawtypes` should be used instead of the old `unchecked` in Eclipse Helios. However, when I use the `rawtypes` annotation, I get following warning:

```
Unhandled warning token rawtypes
```

Even when performing a quick-fix over a raw type, Eclipse suggests me to use `rawtypes`. However, I have found out that the old `unchecked` parameter still works in my version of Helios while `rawtypes` doesn't, which doesn't conform to the docs.

So basically I have already "solved" this issue but the real question is why `rawtypes` doesn't work?

My Eclipse setup:

```
Version: Helios Service Release 2
Build id: 20110301-1815
```

Project setup:

```
Java Build Path > JRE System Library: jdk1.6.0_24
Java Compiler > JDK Compliance: 1.6
Java Compiler > Generated .class files compatibility: 1.6
Java Compiler > Source compatibility: 1.6
```

From `eclipse.ini`:

```
-vm
c:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_24/bin
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```

System:

```
Windows 7 Professional Service Pack 1
```

Any help or explanation will be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Do you have figured out why it doesn't work by now? I have the same problem...

Comment: Sorry I have not, but is seems the problem has gone away by itself. Unfortunately I don't know why...

Comment: It's a year late, but this Stack Overflow item seems to cover the issue:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646770/java-6-unsupported-suppresswarningsrawtypes-warning